# Ionic 4 cannot import custom component is not a know element

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am new to Ionic and I want to create a custom listview with expandable items following this link : https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-accordion-list-in-ionic/.

The problem is that my custom component is never recognized, I have tried many things but nothing works... I am using Ionic 4 and they do not talk of component generation in their doc.

The error is :

```
Error: Template parse errors:
'expandable' is not a known element:
1. If 'expandable' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

[Here is my project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klN3c.png)

expandable.component.html :

```
<div #expandWrapper class='expand-wrapper' [class.collapsed]="!expanded">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

expandable.component.ts :

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-expandable',
  templateUrl: './expandable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./expandable.component.scss']
})
export class ExpandableComponent {

  @ViewChild('expandWrapper', {read: ElementRef}) expandWrapper;
  @Input('expanded') expanded;
  @Input('expandHeight') expandHeight;

  constructor(public renderer: Renderer) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
      this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.expandWrapper.nativeElement, 'height', this.expandHeight + 'px');   
  }

}
```

And here is how I am trying to use it :

```
<expandable [expandHeight]="itemExpandHeight" [expanded]="pet.expanded">
      Hello people
</expandable>
```

Finally, my app.module.ts :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ExpandableComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    DatabaseService, 
    PetService,
    SQLite
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find something?

Comment: Please see my solved answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, you have to create a `component.module.ts` at the root of your component, and then add in your imports `ComponentsModule`

[component.module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUEI9.png)

Answer (score 2):

The issue with the component selector. You have defined the selector `app-expandable` however you are using `expandable`
Replace the below code

```
<expandable [expandHeight]="itemExpandHeight" [expanded]="pet.expanded">
      Hello people
</expandable>
```

by

```
<app-expandable [expandHeight]="itemExpandHeight" [expanded]="pet.expanded">
      Hello people
</app-expandable>
```

### OR

or you change the selector in `ExpandableComponent`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'expandable', //<-- change here
  templateUrl: './expandable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./expandable.component.scss']
})
export class ExpandableComponent {

}
```

Comment: I have already tryed but it doesn't work ... I have the same message.

Comment: Any other ideas please ?

Comment: Please create stackblitz demo for the same.

Comment: I cannot create custom component using stackblitz... And I use ionic 4, stackblitz is ionic 3

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic 3 and 4, what helped me is, to remember that it's not enough to add

```
import { ComponentsModule } from '../../components/components.module';

...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    ComponentsModule,
    ...
  ],
```

to your `app.module.ts`

You also need to add it to every page's module !

```
src/app/home/home.module.ts
src/app/about/about.module.ts
src/app/game/game.module.ts
```

I never liked using the `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` in the `NgModule` ...